# java.mail mark message as unread

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail, read-unread

I am building an automatic mail processor application and I am parsing the emails one by one. If parsing one of the messages fails I would like to mark that message as unread?
How do I mark a message as unread please?

Thank you

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`messageObject.setFlag(Flags.Flag.SEEN, false);`

The first parameter is the Flag, the second one it's if you want to negate that flag, so a Seen with flase is UNSEEN.

PS: You need to use imap, you can't do this with pop3